# Stop Default App Playing File C# UWP

Tags: c#, windows-phone, win-universal-app, surface

I am making a UWP app, I use FileOpenPicker to open media file, but if user double taps the stupid built-in app plays the file and my app looses control. I have set the file associations in the appx.manifest but not change, how can I stop this stupid behaviour?

The function is:

```
public async void PickFromLibrary(string[] fileFilters)
{
    try
    {
        FileOpenPicker openFilePicker = new FileOpenPicker();

        openFilePicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;
        openFilePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.ComputerFolder;

        openFilePicker.FileTypeFilter.Clear();

        foreach( string validExt in fileFilters )
        {
            openFilePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(validExt);
        }

        AppEventArgs.FileEventArgs args = new AppEventArgs.FileEventArgs();
        args.file = await openFilePicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

        AppEvents.OnLocalFilePicked(this, args);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        string msg = e.Message;
    }

}
```

On ARM device opens file (with different app (BAD)) but on x86 phone simulator throws exception when double tapped, I have been looking for a way to disable doubletap in OpenFilePicker but no luck.

Comment: I'm guessing you just need the media file path only, why not used the FolderBrowserDialog instead?

Comment: Please share your code as I used FileOpenPicker to open `.mp4` file an double clicking on it didnt open it in default app but its working as expected.

Comment: I was testing it for desktop UWP app as in OP phone wasnt specified. For desktop this is working fine but for Phone you are right double tapping it tries to open it in default app. Since its an inbuilt functionality the best method would be creating your own custom file picker. Where you will populate your Gridview based on StorageFolder Files present and on SelectedItem retrieve its path.

Comment: Hi Jerin, thanks for the swift reply, yes I was worried that would be the case, I wanted to try an avoid that but this should only take an hour max. Thanks